# ingesting nifi to hdfs to a single directory

Tags: hdfs, apache-nifi, filebeat, elastic-beats

### Scenario

CSV data named test_csv.csv from windows.
Ingesting CSV data to hdfs. Beats > *(ListenBeats)* **NiFi** *(PutHDFS)* > HDFS

## data sample:

```
a,b,c,d,e
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1
a2,b2,c2,d2,e2
a3,b3,c3,d3,e3
a4,b4,c4,d4,e4
a5,b5,c5,d5,e5
a6,b6,c6,d6,e6
a7,b7,c7,d7,e7
a8,b8,c8,d8,e8
```

according to Nifi Flow UI it works fine and successfully written into hdfs. **Problem is**

```
hadoop@ambari:~$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/nifi/test
Found 9 items
-rw-r--r--   3 nifi hdfs        480 2020-07-06 14:30 /user/nifi/test/0192a8bb-67ec-462e-a602-62a5425afc99
-rw-r--r--   3 nifi hdfs        480 2020-07-06 14:30 /user/nifi/test/0211ec05-fc62-4b82-87e5-a2e20a9fb07e
-rw-r--r--   3 nifi hdfs        481 2020-07-06 14:30 /user/nifi/test/1e227df9-f49f-46d6-a309-25e466fa14cf
-rw-r--r--   3 nifi hdfs        480 2020-07-06 14:30 /user/nifi/test/324a0c0e-e190-4239-b594-edbf9fcab0d6
-rw-r--r--   3 nifi hdfs        474 2020-07-06 14:30 /user/nifi/test/3d34827b-6bae-4c21-981e-9722b7a6703e
-rw-r--r--   3 nifi hdfs        481 2020-07-06 14:30 /user/nifi/test/6873c51b-a93b-4872-b33c-0e59b85afcd5
-rw-r--r--   3 nifi hdfs        480 2020-07-06 14:30 /user/nifi/test/98606d6b-2206-4b2e-8204-8363a87f41d0
-rw-r--r--   3 nifi hdfs        480 2020-07-06 14:30 /user/nifi/test/f25e56b5-88d7-4135-b475-213e4e54b47f
-rw-r--r--   3 nifi hdfs        480 2020-07-06 14:30 /user/nifi/test/f354f587-8da2-418f-be0d-34e8a79d7d39
```

i've tried to change *PutHDFS* directory into /user/nifi/test.csv
it returns

```
hadoop@ambari:~$ hdfs dfs -cat /user/nifi/test.csv
cat: `/user/nifi/test.csv': Is a directory
hadoop@ambari:~$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/nifi/test.csv
Found 9 items
-rw-r--r--   3 nifi hdfs        480 2020-07-06 14:35 /user/nifi/test.csv/02cdc89d-3cb9-494a-b7f5-d280d7b7c65e
-rw-r--r--   3 nifi hdfs        480 2020-07-06 14:35 /user/nifi/test.csv/2476906a-00d9-463a-89ef-ea885f823faa
-rw-r--r--   3 nifi hdfs        474 2020-07-06 14:35 /user/nifi/test.csv/5b9a9d7e-0c2f-428c-8af4-e875c6db1a04
-rw-r--r--   3 nifi hdfs        480 2020-07-06 14:35 /user/nifi/test.csv/66017da5-b55f-437b-a3cf-0a6b45d86ce8
-rw-r--r--   3 nifi hdfs        480 2020-07-06 14:35 /user/nifi/test.csv/7be93660-75a1-416b-b019-656d466813d6
-rw-r--r--   3 nifi hdfs        480 2020-07-06 14:35 /user/nifi/test.csv/98877296-126c-4ac9-9da5-cef62937e9f9
-rw-r--r--   3 nifi hdfs        481 2020-07-06 14:35 /user/nifi/test.csv/ac075d33-1137-4aea-9e5b-fc11097558eb
-rw-r--r--   3 nifi hdfs        480 2020-07-06 14:35 /user/nifi/test.csv/b9b44c08-1bc6-4e33-947b-daf265491181
-rw-r--r--   3 nifi hdfs        481 2020-07-06 14:35 /user/nifi/test.csv/ba6464db-ef64-4993-a070-80f1392eac1e
```

is it possible to make nifi write to hdfs in a single directory file?
i was expecing that it will create test.csv file in hdfs

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every flow file in NiFi has an attribute named "filename" and that is what PutHDFS is using as the filename in HDFS. The "Directory" property in PutHDFS is only for the directory, so you want to put only "/user/nifi".

In order to change the filename, you would put an UpdateAttribute processor right before PutHDFS, and set filename = whatever-you-want.csv

If you set it to a static value then every time it writes there is going to be an existing file and be in conflict, either replace or throw an error. So you probably want to use a MergeContent/MergeRecord processor first to batch together many small CSV entries into a larger flow file, and then create a dynamic filename like:

filename = test-${now()}.csv

You can use a different expression, but just something unique like a timestamp, date string, or UUID.

Comment: Dear Bryan, thank you so much for your reply and explanation. I was thinking reckless thought everything dont need custom settings. Seems like you got what i want to make but i still dont get about ``MergeContent`` processor. so is it means, just by using UpdateAttribute filename will be static??

Comment: Usually you want to write large files to HDFS and most likely the flow files coming out of ListenBeats are in KB size, so you want to merge together many of them into a single file before writing to HDFS. You don't have to do this but it is a common pattern.

Comment: If you use UpdateAttribute you can make it a static value, but that wouldn't make sense since you don't want to write the same filename that is already in HDFS, that is why I suggested a dynamic expression like test-${now()}.csv